# Assigning address of an array to another array

Tags: c++

I have a struct like this:

```
struct a
{
string b;
int c;
int *d;
}
```

I also declared:

```
struct a e[i];
```

In the loop:

```
e[i].b= data1;
e[i].c= data2;
e[i].d=&(e[i].b);
```

This is where the problem arises:

```
e[i].d=&(e[i].b);
```

I want to copy the address of string b into d which is a pointer. But I keep getting an error that I can't convert string to int for some reason.

Comment: `e[i].d` is `int*` while `&(e[i].b)` is `string*`. You should perform the cast.

Comment: You aren't assigning any array addresses in your code.

Comment: What is the format for casting addresses Andrey

Comment: you can cast something like this: `(type) variable`

Comment: @AndreyNasonov Casting wouldn't make wrong code any less wrong, it would just prevent the compiler from helping to diagnose the problem.

Comment: A pointer to an `int` cannot usefully point to a`string`. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Member variable b is of type string whereas member variable d is an int pointer. There is no implicit conversion from string* to int*.

You would have to use something like
[reinterpret_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast) to go from string* to int* but I would do my best to avoid something like this as I believe that it breaks strict aliasing rules.

```
e[i].d = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&(e[i].b));
```

I would suggest using a string* instead of an int* to hold the address in the first place. That way you can store the address of your string and maintain the correct type which allows you to use it as a string and not just an address.

```
struct
{
    string b;
    int c;
    string* d;
};
```